# performing validations on p:dialog in JSF form

Tags: javascript, validation, jsf, primefaces

I am using `p:message` for doing validations in `p:dialog` which opend on a button click on the form. So my main form has two dialog boxes which open on button click and these two dialog boxes have a `h:form` in it.

In the main form I have two fields username and password so when the user enter empty values and clicks on submit the error messages are shown on the main form and the dialog also pops up with the error messages which should not be the behavior. I want the validations for the main form to be shown on the form only and the validations for the fields in the `p:dialog` to be shown in the `p:dialog` only. Could you help me on this?

Let me know if any more information is required.

Comment: The way to go is: implement a main form appart from the dialogs (even if you have everything in the same page). Each dialog also has its form inside. That way you divide the content sending properly. For validation, just add a `<p:messages>` tag for main form and other ones inside the dialogs. And, of course, forget about nesting forms (every input element must pertain only to a parent form!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the possibilities is to have a separate `<p:message>` component for every input in every form. This way only the relevant messages will be shown. Example:

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText id="value" ... />
    <p:message for="value>
    ...
</h:form>
<p:dialog>
    <h:form>
        <h:inputText id="value" ... />
        <p:message for="value>
        ...
    </h:form>
<p:dialog>
```

If you'd like to have global messages displayed as well you could consider using a 'hovering' component like [`<p:growl>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/growl.jsf) with `globalOnly="true"`.

Comment: So I have something like this:
<h:messages/>
<h:form id="testForm">
    <h:inputText id="username" required="true"... />
   
    ...
</h:form>
<p:dialog>
    <h:form>
<p:messages/>
        <h:inputText id="emailAddress" ... />
 
    </h:form>
<p:dialog>

Now when i submit the form with empty username it should display a message on the form indicating "Username is required".
So when i click on submit it goes to the bean and the bean validates it and sends this message to the jsf and returns 
the login.xhtml with the messages.the problem is it is displaying on the form and also in the p:dialog.

Comment: What else did you expect putting two `<h/p:messages>` components? You basically **told JSF yourself to display them twice**. Reread the answer once again and try to implement what it says. Come back if you have any difficulties.

Comment: I tried that and its working for individual fields as expected..But I have one more scenario where in when both the field values are entered and the form is submitted the request goes to the bean and validates if the username and password exist and if they do not it should display a message saying "Invalid username and password".How can I achieve that as we are using individual p:messages for each element.Also to be clear I am returning an message from the bean to the page when it fails.Thanks for your help.

Comment: Consider the last statement from the answer. Just do not attach your message to any component and it will show up in `<p:growl globalOnly="true" />` in a 'hovering' manner.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have a question on using p:growl when you navigate to next page.So when i go to one jsf and perform some action if the action is successful I am redirecting the user to the next page.In this scenario the messages are not getting displayed.Do you know how I can do that?